# Geometric series sum $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a}{(1+x)^n}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, geometric-series

Why does this hold

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{a}{(1+x)^n}=\frac{a(x+1)}{x}$$
?

To me it looks like $=\frac{a}{x}$ from the formula.
That is:
$$r=(1+x)^{-n}\Rightarrow a(1-(1+x))^{-n}=a/n$$

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{1+x}}=\frac{1+x}{x}$.

Comment: What restrictions do you have for $x$?

Comment: The restrictions are $0<x<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, do if you put $n=0,1,2..$ in the forumula you'll get,
this series,
$a, \frac{a}{1+x}, \frac{a}{(1+x)^2}...$
with common ration $\frac{1}{1+x}$ now we can use the forumula for sum of $\infty$ GP Which is : $\frac{a}{1-r}$ here $r$ is common ratio;

so we get-$\frac{a}{1-\frac{1}{1-x}}$ which becomes $\frac{a(x+1)}{x}$